# Python: Pandas dataframe re-arrange rows based on last three digits of Integer in Column

Tags: python, sorting, search, integer

I have the following dataframe:

```
YearMonth   Total Cost
2015009     $11,209,041 
2015010     $20,581,043 
2015011     $37,079,415 
2015012     $36,831,335 
2016008     $57,428,630 
2016009     $66,754,405 
2016010     $45,021,707 
2016011     $34,783,970 
2016012     $66,215,044
```

YearMonth is an int64 column.  A value in YearMonth such as 2015009 stands for September 2015.  I want to re-order the rows so that if the last 3 digits are the same, then I want the rows to appear right on top of each other sorted by year.

Below is my desired output:

```
YearMonth   Total Cost
2015009     $11,209,041 
2016009     $66,754,405     
2015010     $20,581,043 
2016010     $45,021,707    
2015011     $37,079,415 
2016011     $34,783,970   
2015012     $36,831,335 
2016012     $66,215,044
2016008     $57,428,630
```

I have scoured google to try and find how to do this but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YearMonth'],format = '%Y0%m')
df['Year'] = df['YearMonth'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df['YearMonth'].dt.month
df.sort_values(['Month','Year'])

        YearMonth   Total   Year    Month
8   2016-08-01  $57,428,630 2016    8
0   2015-09-01  $11,209,041 2015    9
1   2016-09-01  $66,754,405 2016    9
2   2015-10-01  $20,581,043 2015    10
3   2016-10-01  $45,021,707 2016    10
4   2015-11-01  $37,079,415 2015    11
5   2016-11-01  $34,783,970 2016    11
6   2015-12-01  $36,831,335 2015    12
7   2016-12-01  $66,215,044 2016    12
```

One way of doing. There may be a quicker way with fewer steps that don't involve converting `YearMonth` to datetime but if you have a date, it makes more sense to use that.

Answer (score 0):

One way of dong this to cast your int column to string and use the string access with indexing.

```
df.assign(sortkey=df.YearMonth.astype(str).str[-3:])\
  .sort_values('sortkey')\
  .drop('sortkey', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   YearMonth   Total Cost
4    2016008  $57,428,630
0    2015009  $11,209,041
5    2016009  $66,754,405
1    2015010  $20,581,043
6    2016010  $45,021,707
2    2015011  $37,079,415
7    2016011  $34,783,970
3    2015012  $36,831,335
8    2016012  $66,215,044
```